# What protection does casting do?

Tags: java, casting, compiler-errors

The cast to `Bar` is necessary in this code. I'm trying to understand what problem it avoids. If the compiler would let me use the `Foo` as a `Bar` without casting, would it not be able to use the extended functionality that `Bar` could have? Or is there some more important reason? Or is the example too trivial to explain why I must cast?

```
class Foo { }
class Bar extends Foo { }

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo f1 = new Bar();
        Bar b1 = (Bar) f1;
    }
}
```

Can we write a simple example where I see and understand that if I don't cast there will be trouble? I could think that the runtime could help itself without casting in the code above, but certainly I have not understood the deep details why I must do the casting.

Comment: Simplest example: `1 / 2` will result 0 unless you cast one of them to double, so in the code `2 / (1 / 2)` you might get an exception if you don't cast.

Comment: you should take a look at javas [polymorphism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html), it is the concept that forces you to cast in this case.

Answer (score 1):

This protects you from wrong casting. If you will want to use not casted class, which actually is now of type Bar what you will expect to see when using its method? For example you actually make f1 of type Foo, and then you try to make b1 of type Bar point to class Foo. You are trying to invoke method from Bar, but there is no implementation of it. What you expect? Compiler won't know either. In this case if you are trying to cast wrong class you will obtain just `java.lang.ClassCastException`, which we know how to protect from.

Answer (score 1):

The necessity of the cast becomes more clear if you add another class to your hierarchy. Consider this set of classes instead:

```
class Foo {}
class Bar extends Foo {}
class Baz extends Foo {}
```

Now if you have a reference of type `Foo`, it may refer to a `Foo` instance, a `Bar` instance, or a `Baz` instance. Consider this code snippit:

```
Foo f;
if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
    f = new Bar();
} else {
    f = new Baz();
}
```

You can't simply call `f` a `Bar`, because it may be the case that `f` *isn't* a `Bar`, but rather a `Baz`. Hence, the cast is essentially saying , "I know there's a chance this may fail, but I have reason to believe it won't so go ahead and try it". For example, we could do the following:

```
Foo f;
if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
    f = new Bar();
} else {
    f = new Baz();
}

if (f instanceof Bar) {
    Bar b = (Bar) f;
    // do stuff with b...
}
```

Within the `if` block, we have reason to believe that `f` is a `Bar` instance, even though the java compiler can't be sure of that. (In this example it seems trivial, but there could be thousands of lines and multiple stack frames separating the `if` condition and the cast). Hence, we can make the cast with confidence.

If, however, you're wrong about that, that the cast is in fact not valid, you'll get a `ClassCastException` on the line where the cast was attempted. This makes the issue more clear: instead of getting the exception on a random line where the instance in question doesn't have the desired functionality, it happens where the conversion was attempted.